# how to express these areas as union of regions?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

so i understand the idea of seperating the regions so they pass either the vertical line test or horizontal line test, but I'm not sure how to do it while recognizing which functions to use when I break them up. for the first one I'd guess i have to seperate the top half from the bottom half and integrate it as a type 1 region with respect to x, but I'm not sure what functions to use for that picture. The second one I could split it from top to bottom at y = -1/2, but I don't know how to express that in functions. If anyone could show me how to set these up completely showing what functions to use and where to put them in the integral, that'd help my understanding a lot. The book doesn't explain this step too much in depth. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the tilted square region ...
$$  \iint_D dA= \int_{-1}^0\int_{-1}^{-x-1}dy dx 
+  \int_{-1}^0\int_{x+1}^{1}dy dx
\\+  \int_{0}^1\int_{-x+1}^{1}dy dx
+  \int_{0}^1\int_{-1}^{x-1}dy dx
 $$

For the other region...

$$  \iint_D dA= \int_{-1}^0\int_{-1}^{y-y^3}dx dy 
+  \int_{-1}^0\int_{0}^{(x+1)^2}dy dx
\\+  \int_{0}^1\int_{0}^{y-y^3}dx dy
 $$

Comment: how did you get all the equations for the inner integrals?

Comment: for the second one I read them off the graph and for the first one I recognized the straight lines

Comment: how did you get the (x+2)^2?

Comment: my mistake - it should be $(x+1)^2$

Comment: I have now corrected my post